How to combine Typescript generic arguments?
const response = await axios.get<any, AxiosResponse<any, any>, any>('login');

to
const response = await axios.get<CombinedGenerics>('login');

This is needed to reduce the boilerplate.
There does not seem to be a way to destructure the arguments of the type either.
I have tried to scour on instantiation expression (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html), but it is not what I am looking for.

you may use something like
type CombinedGenerics<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any> = {
  responseType: T;
  axiosResponseType: R;
  dataType: D;
};

